# $(X^Y)^Z\cong X^{(Y+Z)}$ or $(X^Y)^Z\cong X^{(Y\times Z)}$?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, hom-functor

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$I have the following exercise in my class of Category Theory:

Prove that $\text{Hom}(Z,\Hom(Y,X))\cong \Hom(Y*Z, X)$ but I am not sure what $*$ is. I think that $*$ should be $+$ (by $+$ I mean the co-product). Because at [$\operatorname{Hom}(X \times Z, Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(X, \operatorname{Map}(Z, Y))$ is not true in $\textbf{Top}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450917/operatornamehomx-times-z-y-cong-operatornamehomx-operatornamemap) it was discussed that $\Hom(Z,\Hom(Y,X))\not \cong \Hom(Y\times Z, X)$.

But I have been trying to find a bijection between $\Hom(Z,\Hom(Y,X))$ and $\Hom(Y+Z, X)$.

I have a map going from $\Hom(Z,\Hom(Y,X))$ to $\Hom(Y+Z, X)$:
First of all note that $\Hom(Y+Z, X)$ is in bijection with $\Hom(Y,X)\times\Hom(Z,X). This is very clear; see for example [Hom Functor Preserves Coproducts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173882/hom-functor-preserves-coproducts).

So I need to find for each $f:Z\rightarrow \Hom(Y,X)$ maps $Y\rightarrow X$ and $Z\rightarrow X$. To get them I do the following: for each $y\in Y$ and $z\in Z$ I define
$$Y\to X; y\mapsto z(y)$$
and
$$Z\to X;z\mapsto z(y).$$

But I don't know how to get arrows in the other direction.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}(Z, \operatorname{Hom}(Y, X))$ does not make sense in an abstract category $\mathcal C$, since $\operatorname{Hom}(Y, X)$ is not *a priori* an element of $\mathcal C$.  (Note that your linked question has to impose a topology—the compact-open topology—on $\operatorname{Map}(Y, X)$.)  What is the additional structure that allows us to make sense of this nested Hom-set?

Comment: What if we are in the set category?

Comment: [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401861/xyz-cong-xyz-or-xyz-cong-xy-times-z#comment9207598_4401861) this is a question in set theory, not category theory, and you can check that $(X^Y)^Z \cong X^{Y \times Z}$ *via* the obvious (un)currying map.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Comment: If we had $(X^Y)^Z \cong X^{Y+Z}$ instead of $X^{Y\times Z}$, then $A^B$ for the set of functions $B\to A$ would be a very bad choice of notation!